# Is it possible to run a script when Icinga2 a host has a critical service?

Tags: nagios, icinga, icinga2

Let's say a given host, `FooHost`, is running Apache2. Icinga2 runs a check by ssh command and discovers that Apache2 is not running, which triggers a critical alert.

Is it possible to have Icinga2 execute a script on this event? In this example, I would like to write a script that does an SSH remote execute of `systemctl restart apache2`.

In the alternative, we could write a watchdog script that could be deployed on *all* servers, but it makes MUCH more sense to write it on the Icinga2 box, and use ssh remote execute because that allows central control.

I see no reason to have to have an engineer log in to fix this unless this restart failed also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Event Commands](https://icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/03-monitoring-basics/#event-commands) (like Event Handlers in Icinga 1.x / Nagios) to achieve this.

The documentation show the following example, which is using a custom *shell* script to perform the restart operations:

```
object EventCommand "restart_service" {
  command = [ PluginDir + "/restart_service" ]

  arguments = {
    "-s" = "$service.state$"
    "-t" = "$service.state_type$"
    "-a" = "$service.check_attempt$"
    "-S" = "$restart_service$"
  }

  vars.restart_service = "$procs_command$"
}

object Service "Process httpd" {
  check_command = "procs"
  event_command = "restart_service"
  max_check_attempts = 4

  host_name = "icinga2-client1.localdomain"
  command_endpoint = "icinga2-client1.localdomain"

  vars.procs_command = "httpd"
  vars.procs_warning = "1:10"
  vars.procs_critical = "1:"
}
```

Comment: provide some context to support the links just in case they go broken.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know it is not possible but you can use
an **nagios nrpe command** or a **cronjob** which is execute command like this

```
pgrep apache2 || /bin/systemctl restart apache2 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

or

```
/bin/systemctl status apache2 || /bin/systemctl restart apache2
```

which means if the apache2 service is not running it will be restarted.